# Navigate to a particular master list item sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5, master-detail, sap-fiori

I have a Master-Detail page. After doing some transaction ( editing some data ) on the detail page, I want to stay on that item of Master list with the refreshed data. But after editing and refreshing the model, the page navigates to the first item of the Master list rather than staying on the same item of the master list and it's detail page. Below is the code after editing the data :

Detail.controller.js :

```
    update: function (evt) {
            that.oDataModel.update("/RaiseQuerySet('" + that.detailModel.getData().EICNO + "')", 
            this.data, null, function (data) {

                                MessageBox.success("Your query has been updated", {
                                    onClose: function (sAction) {
                                        that.cancelIndent();
                                        that.refreshPage();

                                    }
                                });

    }

    refreshPage: function () {
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZHR_V_CARE_SRV/EmpQueryInitSet('10002001')?$expand=QueryLoginToQueryList/QueryToLog",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                that.getView().getModel("totalModel").setData(data.d.QueryLoginToQueryList);

                that.router.navTo('DetailPage', {
                    QueryNo: that.detailModel.getData().EICNO
                });
            //
            that.totalModel.refresh(true);
                that.detailModel.refresh(true);
            }
        });
    },


cancelIndent: function (evt) {
        this.detailModel.refresh(true);
    }
```

DetailModel is used to populate the data in the detail page and totalModel is used to populate the data in the master page.

Comment: Why do you jump through so many hoops when you could simply bind your app directly to the OData model?

Comment: @Marc Can you please quote some example so that it would be helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: It has a lot of steps but the official walkthrough should get you started: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if inside the manifest.json file you have 2 targets linked with route DetailPage.

From the behavior you explained, I would say that is the case.

The master detail templates from WebIDE usually have a logic inside the ListSelector.js file on which every time the master list it’s displayed it selects the first item automatically.